# Currency Convertor in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I have created this simple currency convertor to learn VueJs more. Any code review/comment on coding standard and best practice for Vue? Thanks in advance.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      currency_from_amount: 0,
      currency_to_amount: 0,
      result: '',
      currencyFromOptions: [],
      currencyToOptions: [],
      loading: true,
      errored: false,
      info: null,
      currencyFromSelected: '',
      currencyToSelected: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    validation: function() {
      return (this.currency_from_amount > 0 && this.currencyFromSelected.length === 3 && this.currencyToSelected.length === 3)
    },
    convert: function() {
      debugger

      let payLoad = `${this.currencyFromSelected}_${this.currencyToSelected}`;
      //let payLoad = `USD_MYR`;
      console.log(payLoad);
      if(this.validation()) {
        this.loading = true;
        axios
          .get(
            `https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=${payLoad}&compact=ultra&apiKey=afd6156ec2a14519570e`
          )
          .then((response) => {
              debugger
              let exchangeRate = JSON.stringify(response).replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');

              let conversionAmt = (parseFloat(this.currency_from_amount) * parseFloat(
                exchangeRate)).toFixed(2);

              this.currency_to_amount = conversionAmt;
              this.result = `${this.currency_from_amount} ${this.currencyFromSelected} equals ${conversionAmt} ${this.currencyToSelected}`;
            }

          )
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.errored = true;
          })
          .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("https://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json")
      .then(response => (this.currencyFromOptions = response.data, this.currencyToOptions = response
        .data))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errored = true;
      })
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Currency Convertor in vue</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    .form-group select {
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
  <div id="app">
    <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
    <section v-else>
      <div class="alert alert-success" id="result" v-if="validation">{{result}}</div>

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
          <input class="form-control" type="number" name="currency_from_amount" id="currency_from_amount" v-model="currency_from_amount" @keyup="convert">

          <select class="form-control" required v-model="currencyFromSelected" @change="convert">
            <option v-for="(value,key) in currencyFromOptions" :value="key">{{ value }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
          <input class="form-control" type="number" name="currency_to_amount" id="currency_to_amount" readonly v-model="currency_to_amount">

          <select class="form-control" v-model="currencyToSelected" @change="convert">
            <option v-for="(value,key) in currencyToOptions" :value="key">{{ value }}</option>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Note: Data provided by CurrencyConverterApi.com for Currency</p>
    </section>

    </select>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should always use `const` instead of `let` or `var` if you are not going to be reassigning that variable.

Comment: I agree, though it would help to add a reason.

Comment: I did I said if you are not going to be reassing that variable.

Comment: That sounds like a condition - thus it could be reworded as "_if you are not going to be reassigning that variable **then** you should use `const` instead of `let` or `var`_"... Imagine you are not well-versed in the differences between those keywords - one might ask "why?"...

Comment: Thank you Sam I was not aware of this.

Comment: The *reason* is to help prevent you from making mistakes in the future by accidentally overwriting a variable unexpectedly. See here: https://evertpot.com/javascript-let-const/

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, I think it would be better if you use same format in your `data()`. There you mixed between `camelCase` and `snake_case`. I don't know about your approach but make it more consistent would be better and I think it won't make you confused in the future.

```javascript
currency_from_amount: 0,
currency_to_amount: 0,
```

to

```javascript
currencyFromAmount: 0,
currencyToAmount: 0,
```